# How to avoid <> in HTML?

Tags: html, syntax, syntax-error

I would like to paste into my HTML code a phrase

```
"<car>"
```

and I would like that this word "car" will be between <>. In some text will be

```
"<car>"
```

and this is not a HTML expression. The problem is that when I put it the parser think that this is the HTML syntax how to avoid it. Is there any expression which need to be between this?

Answer (score 4):

replace `<` by `&lt;` and `>` by `&gt;`

[Live on JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/M8Edr/)

[< and > are special characters, more special characters in HTML you can find here.](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php)

[More about HTML entities you can find here.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "greater than" and "less than" entities:

```
&lt;car&gt;
```

The W3C, the organization responsible for setting web standards, has some [pretty good documentation on HTML entities](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Common_HTML_entities_used_for_typography). They consist of an ampersand followed by an entity name followed by a semicolon (`&name;`) or an ampersand followed by a pound sign followed by an entity number followed by a semicolon (`&#number;`). The link I provided has a table of common HTML entities.

Comment: That's two downvotes now... anyone care to comment on what the issue is?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Interesting. I can't seem to find much of anything backing that site up, but I'll drop the W3Schools link and replace it with a W3C link.

Answer (score 0):

use `&gt;` for > and `&lt;` for <

```
$gt;car&lt;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use special character .. To know more about Special Character [link here](http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html)

**CODE:**

```
<p>&quot;&lt;car &gt;&quot;</p>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
 "<car>"
```

Answer (score 0):

`<` = `&lt;` *less than*

`>` = `&gt;` *greater than*

The same applies for `XML` too.  Take a look here, [`special characters for HTML`](http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want LESS THAN SIGN “<” to appear visibly in page content, write it as `&amp;`, so that it will not be treated as starting a tag. Ref.: [5.3.2 Character entity references](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/charset.html#didx-character_entity_references) in HTML 4.01.

So you would write

```
&lt;car>
```

If you like, you can write “>” as `&gt;` for symmetry, but there is no need to.

But if you really want to put something in angle brackets, e.g. using a mathematical notation, rather than a markup notation (as in HTML and XML), consider using U+27E8 MATHEMATICAL LEFT ANGLE BRACKET “⟨” and U+27E9 MATHEMATICAL RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET “⟩”. They cause no problems to HTML markup, as they are not markup-significant. If you don’t know how to type them in your authoring environment, you can use character references for them:

```
&#x27e8;car&#x27e9;
```

This would result in ⟨car⟩, though as always with less common special characters, you would need to consider [character (font) problems](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/characters.html).